# No webpage was found for the web address Azurewebsite

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I deploy my application to Azurewebsite, and while I am testing application I found one error.
When I want to add product to Bag, the Bag doesnt show that product is added, and when I press icon for Bag it's show error

```
This granihouse.azurewebsites.net page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: https://granihouse.azurewebsites.net/Customer/ShoppingCart
HTTP ERROR 404
```

What I did so far, is that I try to deploy application on localhost IIS and take files and transfer to server by using FileZilla and nothing didnt change.
Second thing what I did is try to change connection string and try to deploy application in Visual Studio but againg same problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GraniteHouse.Data;
using GraniteHouse.Extensions;
using GraniteHouse.Models;
using GraniteHouse.Models.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace GraniteHouse.Areas.Customer.Controllers
{
    [Area("Customer")]
    public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        [BindProperty]
        public ShoppingCartViewModel ShoppingCartVM { get; set; }

        public ShoppingCartController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            ShoppingCartVM = new ShoppingCartViewModel()
            {
                Products = new List<Models.Products>()
            };
        }

        //Get Index Shopping Cart
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            List<int> lstShoppingCart = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<int>>("ssShoppingCart");
            if(lstShoppingCart.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(int cartItem in lstShoppingCart)
                {
                    Products prod = _db.Products.Include(p => p.SpecialTags).Include(p => p.ProductTypes).Where(p => p.Id == cartItem).FirstOrDefault();
                    ShoppingCartVM.Products.Add(prod);
                }
            }
            return View(ShoppingCartVM);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [ActionName("Index")]
        public IActionResult IndexPost()
        {
            List<int> lstCartItem = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<int>>("ssShoppingCart");

            ShoppingCartVM.Appointments.AppointmentDate = ShoppingCartVM.Appointments.AppointmentDate
                                                                        .AddHours(ShoppingCartVM.Appointments.AppointmentTime.Hour)
                                                                        .AddMinutes(ShoppingCartVM.Appointments.AppointmentTime.Minute);
            Appointments appointments = ShoppingCartVM.Appointments;
            _db.Appointments.Add(appointments);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            int appointmentId = appointments.Id;

            foreach (int productId in lstCartItem)
            {
                ProductsSelectedForAppointment productSelectedForAppointment = new ProductsSelectedForAppointment()
                {
                    AppointmentId = appointmentId,
                    ProductId = productId

                };
                _db.ProductsSelectedForAppointment.Add(productSelectedForAppointment);

            }
            _db.SaveChanges();
            lstCartItem = new List<int>();
            HttpContext.Session.Set("ssShoppingCart", lstCartItem);

            return RedirectToAction("AppointmentConfirmation", "ShoppingCart", new { Id = appointmentId});
        }



        public IActionResult Remove(int id)
        {
            List<int> lstCartItem = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<int>>("ssShoppingCart");

            if(lstCartItem.Count > 0)
            {
                if(lstCartItem.Contains(id))
                {
                    lstCartItem.Remove(id);
                }
            }
            HttpContext.Session.Set("ssShoppingCart", lstCartItem);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }


        //Get
        public IActionResult AppointmentConfirmation(int id)
        {
            ShoppingCartVM.Appointments = _db.Appointments.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            List<ProductsSelectedForAppointment> objProdList = _db.ProductsSelectedForAppointment.Where(p => p.AppointmentId == id).ToList();


            foreach(ProductsSelectedForAppointment prodAtpObj in objProdList)
            {
                ShoppingCartVM.Products.Add(_db.Products.Include(p => p.ProductTypes).Include(p => p.SpecialTags).Where(p => p.Id == prodAtpObj.ProductId).FirstOrDefault());
            }
            return View(ShoppingCartVM);
        }
    }
}
```

It's look like that Azure doesn't recognize ShoppingCart controller.
Any suggestion what can be problem ?

Comment: are you deploying published content or source code?

Comment: Content of my website

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-deploy-web-app-to-azure-using-visual-studio/ in this link you can see how to deploy to azure in bottom section

Comment: I know how to publish, but I get error while I using application on Azure. You think that error comes from deploy ?

Comment: there is some thing wrong in the way you are publishing to azure. you might be missing few steps

Comment: Thank you, I will try to re-publish application :)

Comment: Still noo, I try to re-publish application a couple of time and I still get same error
No webpage was found for the web address: https://granithouse.azurewebsites.net/Customer/ShoppingCart
HTTP ERROR 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your site runs fine locally, I would check on how your dependencies are configured. When I visit https://granihouse.azurewebsites.net/ I receive a timeout error. Assuming that you're using Right-Click Publish inside Visual Studio, I'm thinking there's an issue with what `ApplicationDbContext` is pointing to your app service. Also, `lstShoppingCart` could be null which means NullReferenceException could be thrown when checking `.Count` in which case your View won't be returned.

Comment: Sure, But when I press Add to Bag button, it should increce Bag to (1), but this doesnt happened, and when I press Bag View it's display NullReferenceException

Comment: I'm assuming Bag is `HttpContext.Session.Get<List<int>>("ssShoppingCart");` and if so, how/when are you setting `HttpContext.Session["ssShoppingCart"]`?

Comment: Hill I didnt set it. Once I run application it works fine, and after a couple of time I run it I get run time error. NullReferenceException

Comment: If you're not setting it, then that is what's causing your NullReferenceException. One thing you could do is use a null coalescent `if (lstShoppingCart?.Count > 0)` which will return false if the `lstShoppingCart` is null.

Comment: Yes, I change it and now I can open Shopping Cart form 
But one think which I notice now is that Bag is now showing that items is added to  Bag.

Comment: More than likely because the session hasn't timed out. [Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout?view=netframework-4.8) is 20 minutes